# Compute $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{2^{1/n}}{n+1} + \frac{2^{2/n}}{n+1/2} +…+ \frac{2^{n/n}}{n+1/n})$

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

Its  weird as I have a solution but neither I'm satisfied by my method nor I can find why is this wrong. 
We write the sum after some simple steps as $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^{n}  \frac{r2^{r/n}}{r+1/n}$$
Now we can say that $\frac{r}{r+1/n} \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$
Thus we have the riemann sum $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^{n}  2^{r/n}$$ which when solved gives the value $$\int_0^1 2^x dx = \frac{1}{\ln 2}$$

Comment: I think you want the upper limit of the first sum to be $n$. I also don't get why $\frac{r}{r+1/n} \to 1 $ means you get replace that term in the sum with with $1$

Comment: As an option, 
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^n  \frac{r\,2^{r/n}}{r+1/n}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^n  \frac{(r+1/n-1/n)\,2^{r/n}}{r+1/n}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^n  2^{r/n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{r=1}^n  \frac{2^{r/n}}{r+1/n}$$
where 
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1}^n2^{r/n}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{2^{1/n}}{2^{1/n}-1};\quad 0<\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{r=1}^n  \frac{2^{r/n}}{r+1/n}<\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{r=1}^n  \frac{2}{r}<\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^2}\int_1^n\frac{dr}{r}$$
The limit follows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noting
$$ n<n+\frac 1k <n+1$$
one has
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k/n}}{n+1}<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k/n}}{n+\frac1k}<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k/n}}{n}. $$
Since
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k/n}}{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k/n}=\int_0^12^xdx=\frac1{\ln2}$$
and
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k/n}}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k/n}=\int_0^12^xdx=\frac1{\ln2}$$
so
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k/n}}{n+\frac1k}=\frac1{\ln2}. $$